# I am receiving the following error when executing my code - EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I have written the following code to create a binary search tree from a given input and to find the min value of the tree.

Input:

First line of input contains the number of test cases T. For each test case, there will be only a single line of input which is a string representing the tree as described below:

Example:

```
2
5 4 6 3 N N 7 1
9 N 10 N 11
```

The values in the string are in the order of level order traversal of the tree where, numbers denotes node values, and a character “N” denotes NULL child.

Here is the link for the problem: [Minimum element in BST](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/minimum-element-in-bst/1).

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.val=value
        self.left=None
        self.right=None

    class BST:
        def __init__(self,value):
            self.root=node(value)

        def insert(self,value):
            if self.root==None:
                self.root=node(value)
            else:
                self._insert(value,self.root)

        def _insert(self,value,curr):
            if value<curr.val:
                if curr.left==None:
                    curr.left=node(value)
                else:
                    self._insert(value,curr.left)
            elif value>curr.val:
                if curr.right==None:
                    curr.right=node(value)
                else:
                    self._insert(value,curr.right)

        def print_tree(self):
            if self.root!=None:
                self._print_tree(self.root)

        def _print_tree(self,cur_node):
            if cur_node!=None:
                self._print_tree(cur_node.left)
                print (str(cur_node.val))
                self._print_tree(cur_node.right)

        def min_val(self):
            if self.root==None:
                return -1
            else:
                self._min_val(self.root)

        def _min_val(self,curr_node):
            if curr_node.left==None:
                print(curr_node.val)
            else:
                self._min_val(curr_node.left)
        ##Your code here

    t=int(input())        #number of test cases
    for j in range(t):
        a=input()
        lst=a.split(" ")
        root=int(lst[0])
        tree=BST(root)
        for i in range(1,len(lst)):
            if lst[i]!=N:
                tree.insert(int(lst[i]))

        tree.min_val()
```

Where am I going wrong? Whenever I run the code it says EOF error. But the same code works perfectly fine in my IDE with custom inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to start you have some syntax errors there:

```
if lst[i]!=N:

->

if lst[i] != 'N':
```

```
class node:
def __init__(self,value):

->

class node:
    def __init__(self,value):
```

Also can you share the error you get?

**EDIT:**
Looking at the question:

> The task is to complete the function minValue() which takes root as the argument and returns the minimum element of BST.

You should only provide `minValue(root)` and nothing else. Reading the input will be handled for you by the test engine.

Comment: Runtime Error:
Runtime ErrorTraceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/7fd6b1fd690b2e3e7a30e687149b09b7.py", line 140, in <module>
   
t=int(input())

EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the syntax errors, I have edited it and still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @HBK8396: that full traceback should go in your question, instead of the vague "it says EOF error".

Comment: @HBK8396: it would be more useful if you actually did that edit.